# If I call a function on a view that is destroyed, does it blow up?

Tags: java, android, view

Lets say I have the following code

```
class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    onCreate()
    {
        SomeView view = (SomeView) findViewById(R.id.some_view);

        // [code here destroys the inflated layout, including SomeView]

        // Does the android specification guarantee that the following
        // line of code is ALWAYS safe to execute?
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Will it just not change anything (e.g. modifying something that is non-existent) or will it blow up with a million exceptions. The reason I am asking this question and not just testing it on an emulator is that I want to be sure I am doing something that is "best practice" or "guaranteed" safe by the android specs.

Comment: There will be no exceptions and so no worries!

Comment: @Xenolion If you make it an answer and cite a source I can accept you

Comment: I dont know even where to cite. But I have used it just be experience!

Comment: @Xenolion there will be nullpointerexception if view is destroyed. In kotlin you can make null-safe method invocation `view?.set...` and it will not execute if view doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah it will be a null pointer only if the view is not in a current layout! but if it is there there is no null pointers!

Comment: @Xenolion Well then this is a problem... `[code here destroys the inflated layout, including SomeView]
`

Comment: I dont get it when you say destroy a view!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you destroy the view, then yes, it will throw NPE when you try to operate on that view. Its just as if you nullify some object and try to do some operation on that object.

Comment: Then how come `view.getParent().removeAllViews()` doesn't throw any errors? Is it because `removed` != `destroyed`? If thats the case when is a view "destroyed"? by the garbage collector?